# Did I mess up my mead?

Tags: mead

I am attempting to make 1.5 liters of mead as a first go.

I was very lazy though and used a whole packet of lalvin 71b-1122 on such a small batch.

1 week has gone by.  The color looks good but everything has settled to the bottom.  Did it just eat everything super fast?  Is it ruined?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll have ruined the batch just by using so much yeast to start. The yeast simply wouldn't have needed to reproduce as much as they normally do so the fermentation would have started faster and subsequently finished faster.

When you say everything has settled to the bottom are you referring to fruit and spices you added for flavour? or just the yeast cake on the bottom?

Either way, one week is plenty long enough for most if not all the yeast to settle, I think you'll be fine. Hope it tastes as good as you hoped it would.

Comment: thx tony.  it was just the yeast.  i didnt add any fruit.  it was honey from my beehive so I hope that is enough.

Comment: I think you'll be fine, hope its good :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably fine, but there are some possible bad side effects to the flavor from over-pitching. Per the wyeast website:

> High pitch rates can lead to:
>   Very low ester production
>   Very fast fermentations
>   Thin or lacking body/mouthfeel
>   Autolysis (Yeasty flavors due to lysing of cells)

Comment: I agree on this: There might be side effects to the taste. However, I'm unsure if there's a difference between fresh and dry yeast in that respect.